# Acrobat Forms: Enforcing 'Display Value' into Flattened PDF Field

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, acrobat

I have an Acrobat Forms document (PDF) which contains a combo box with export values associated with each entry (*annotation* aka *display value*).

When I flatten the PDF, the combo box automatically gets replaced by the **export value** of the selected value of the combo box. (I believe this is natural, because that's what the *export value* facility is supposed to do: show one value in the live form and show a different value in the exported (flattened) document.
E.g. if the field contains an entry with 'Stack Overflow' as the display value and 'www.stackoverflow.com' as the export value, the live form would display the former and the flattened document will contain the latter.)

However, I would like the flattened form to retain the **display value** of the field rather than the **export value** (i.e. 'Stack Overflow' rather than 'www.stackoverflow.com' in the earlier example). I have gone through the Acrobat JavaScript API documentation several times, but could not find any satisfactory solution.

Is there some way to accomplish this? Any possible approach via Acrobat JavaScript API is acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question really is this: Is there any way I can change the behavior of a form that has burned into it a particular behavior? The answer is simple. Yes. Change the PDFs behavior by creating a new one that behaves as you want it to.

Comment: Well, the point is that I need the actual form to retain the 'export value' functionality (while one copy of the form is being flattened, another copy is being e-mailed to a recipient).
I was hoping to find a more elegant solution than temporarily changing the form's behaviour (i.e. somehow 'disabling' export value functionality of the copy which is to be flattened).

Thanks anyway! I'll try out your suggestion.